# SurfaceView - Bitmap's are glitchy when detecting input

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, surfaceview, android-canvas

I've created a game loop in Android by extending the `SurfaceView` class and the `Thread` class similar to the Lunar Lander example in the Android Samples. Right now I'm just trying to find a way to let users drag Bitmaps around the screen using `onTouchEvent` to receive information on where was touched and then seeing if it was within the bounds of one of my Bitmaps and moving that Bitmap's X and Y position accordingly. This works sometimes although at other times it may move an image to where I touch even if it's well outside the bounds of it and so long as I pressed down close to other images.

I have no idea where this buggy behaviour is coming from, I'm yet to implement any way of slowing down the thread so that it doesn't use max CPU - could this be making it laggy which produces these results? If anyone could shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it.

I'm getting the user input and passing to a custom method `handleAction'(actionName)'`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        thread.handleActionDown((int) event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (thread.isTouched()) {
            thread.handleActionMove((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        }   
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (thread.isTouched()) {
            thread.handleActionUp();
        }
    }       
    return true;
}
```

Here are my handler methods:

`tizer` is a Bitmap and TizerX & Y are class variables for its X and Y position, it's the same for `ball`.

```
public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY) {
    if (eventX >= (TizerX - tizer.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (TizerX + tizer.getWidth() / 2))) {
        if (eventY >= (TizerY - tizer.getHeight() / 2) && (TizerY <= (TizerY + tizer.getHeight() / 2))) {
            setTouched(true);
            if(getBitmapTouched() == "") {
                setBitmapTouched("tizer");
            }               
        } else {
            setTouched(false);
            setBitmapTouched(null);
        }
    } else if (eventX >= (BallX - ball.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (BallX + ball.getWidth() / 2))) {
        if (eventY >= (BallY - ball.getHeight() / 2) && (BallY <= (BallY + ball.getHeight() / 2))) {
            setTouched(true);
            if(getBitmapTouched() == "") {
                setBitmapTouched("ball");
            }   
        } else {
            setTouched(false);
            setBitmapTouched("");
        }
    } else {
        setTouched(false);
        setBitmapTouched("");
    }
}

public void handleActionUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setTouched(false);
    setBitmapTouched("");
}


public void handleActionMove(int eventX, int eventY) {
    if(isTouched()) {
        if(getBitmapTouched() == "tizer") {
            setTizerX(eventX);
            setTizerY(eventY);
        } else if (getBitmapTouched() == "ball") {
            setBallX(eventX);
            setBallY(eventY);
        }           
    }
```

My thread constantly calls the `doDraw` method:

```
private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Draw the background image. Operations on the Canvas accumulate
    // so this is like clearing the screen.
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(testBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(tizer, TizerX - (tizer.getWidth() / 2), TizerY - (tizer.getHeight() / 2), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, BallX - (ball.getWidth() / 2), BallY - (ball.getHeight() / 2), null);
}
```

Despite looking through countless examples on the internet and Stack Overflow on the correct way to see if a Bitmap has been touched I still have yet to get it right, I don't receive an error in the LogCat so I don't have anything else to show, if you managed to spot something in the code that seems odd please let me know.